# Noninteractive recursive copy on Windows

Tags: windows, batch, copy

I'd like to copy a local directory recursively to another local directory on Windows 10, with the following requirements:

- The copy operation must not ask any questions while it is running. (This is important, because I expect it to run for 20 hours, and I'm not available to click OK during that.) If an error happens, it must be reported, and the copy must continue with the next file.
- If the destination file already exists, the copy must overwrite it iff the size differs. (Otherwise the file must be skipped.)
- The copy must copy last modification times for files and directories.
- It doesn't matter whether the copy copies the owner, permissions or extended attributes.
- The copy must work for pathnames longer than 255 characters.
- The copy must run as Administrator, so that it has the read and write access to all files and directories.

I tried copying in Total Commander, but it tends to interrupt the copy with various questions. I wasn't able to start a copy in way that I answer all possible questions at start time. (I was able to specify in the settings to copy the last modification times of directories. By default it was disabled.)

Comment: Look at [RoboCopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy).  You will need to figure out the 50,000 command line options.  "The copy must run as Administrator".. that clearly is up to you to manage.. I have to wonder why you listed this as a requirement.  Total Commander can be dangerous.  For instance, use it to associate exe files with notepad.  It will happily let you and the explorer will henceforth do this ever time you attempt to run an exe.

Comment: The requirement to run as Administrator is there as a preference for solutions for which it is easy to do so.

Comment: @pts - Can you clarify your question instead of submitting a comment?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Many tools, including Total Commander and RoboCopy can be dangerous, for example both of these tools can be used to delete a large number of files in a single action.

Comment: @pts, Robocopy doesn't edit file associations in the registry without checking things like exe or com.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas: Sure, tools can be dangerous in different ways. For example, RoboCopy doesn't give the user a quick display of source and destionation folders, thus it's easier for the user to specify a wrong source or a wrong destination by mistake, causing good files to be irrecoverably overwritten with bad content (if the `/is` flag was specified).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start cmd.exe as Administrator. Within that black console window, run:

```
robocopy C:\SRCDIR D:\DSTDIR /e /dcopy:dat /r:0
```

It fulfills all the requirements in the question, with one modification: it skips copying a file iff the destination has a file with the same pathname, size and last modification time. (The question requires a check for size only, ignoring the last modification time.)

Also it follows symlinks, so it falls to an infinite loop, never finishing: `C:\Users\All Users\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\...`

Comment: To the downvoter: is there anything I should improve in this answer?

Answer (score 1):

[Dsynchronize](http://www.dimio.altervista.org/eng/#DSynchronize) can do all of this.